# Missing or disappear home directory

Tags: linux, debian, users, home, rescue

Today I turn on my computer and I get many problems fsck with nodes after (Initramfs), this happened to me before so I run the following command

```
fsck /dev/sda1 -y
```

now running this command apparently solved the problem I turn on my laptop with normally, the following problem that I find into was that I could not do loggin in my laptop so with

```
ctrl + alt + f1
```

came to console I do loggin with my username and password appears to me that there is not home directory and for that reason could not login. While this is a big problem could not do anything, necessarily create a user and this create a new home folder and my new user. and can perform the login quietly.

Now as I can get my initial home folder I have a lot of information and this disappear or maybe the command delete it. how I can get my original folder /home/olduser? obviously the new user contains nothing